# Using zip() inside shiny downloadHandler produces error "invalid path argument"

Tags: r, shiny

When trying to generate a zip file in a shiny downloadHandler() function using the usual connection, R throws an error ("invalid path agrument").

The use of `downloadHandler()` produces an error of the type `invalid path argument` and `Warning: Error in zip: 'zipfile' must be a string or a connection`, despite writing to the usual connection (`file`)

The following functions creates a zip file by combining multiple xlsx-files based on some pattern (i.e. only xlsx-files with the current date in the file name).

```r
    output$export_excel_zip <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        "external_output_excel.zip"
      },
      content = function(file) {
        source("99_export-external.R", local = TRUE)
        
        # Get list of files in the directory once
        file_list <- list.files("download/external")
        
        # Filter files based on conditions
        today_date <- str_sub(Sys.time(), 1, 10)
        files_to_zip <- file_list[str_detect(file_list, pattern = paste0(today_date)) & str_detect(file_list, ".xlsx")]
        
        zip(zipfile = file, files = file.path("download", "external", files_to_zip))

      },
      contentType = "application/zip"
    )
```

I also tried generating the zip file first via

```r
zip(zipfile = file.path("download", "external", "external_output_excel.zip"), files = file.path("download", "external", files_to_zip))
```

as an intermediate step, and then use

```r
filecopy(from = "external_output_excel.zip", to = file)
```

but same outcome. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to run the code outside the Shiny framework and check if you get your desired result.

Comment: using  

`zip(zipfile = file(tempfile(fileext = ".zip")), files = file.path("download", "external", files_to_zip))`  

gives  

`Error in path.expand(zipfile) : invalid 'path' argument`  

using  

`zip(zipfile = file.path("download", "external", "test.zip"), files = file.path("download", "external", files_to_zip))`  

creates the file `test.zip` without problems

Comment: Try to print the file argument before zipping, what's the outcome ? Maybe there is kind of encoding error or something

Comment: in the initial code, the `zipfile` argument is the stream of the `downloadHandler()`, this gives when inspecting

`function (description = "", open = "", blocking = TRUE, encoding = getOption("encoding"), 
    raw = FALSE, method = getOption("url.method", "default")) 
{
    .Internal(file(description, open, blocking, encoding, method, 
        raw))
}
<bytecode: 0x5568835e9e50>`

Comment: When creating a tmp file stream

`> file(tempfile(fileext = ".zip"))
A connection with                                                  
description "/tmp/RtmpgHFLk9/file72e12734e747.zip"
class       "file" 
mode        "r"
text        "text"
opened      "closed" 
can read    "yes" 
can write   "yes" 
> zip(zipfile = file(tempfile(fileext = ".zip")), files = file.path("download", "external", files_to_zip))
Error in path.expand(zipfile) : invalid 'path' Argument`

Comment: sry about the messy comments, don't know how to format them better